# Install in user site-package

Tags: python, easy-install, manual

I have red at the help-page of `easy_install` that I have an ability to do "install in user site-package". What does this phase mean, "user site-package"? How does it affect functionality of the installed software?

Comment: more detailed info https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User site-package refers to packages installed in ~/.local/lib[64]/python-VERSION/site-packages/

These packages are available as any other installed packages, but only to this specific user. It overrides system packages too.